# "Loading .NET Framework" message when loading an empty workbook in Excel

Tags: excel

When opening a particular Excel file, it takes 4 minutes for the message `Loading .NET Framework...` to clear up. Once it opens, it works fast, as expected. The only suggestion I found was to launch Excel in safe mode. It has the same behavior. I deleted all worksheets, connections to exterior databases, Power Query, VBA, names, and I saved it as XLSX. Still the same behavior.
If I close the spreadsheet (but not Excel) and open it again, it opens fast.

What's even more puzzling is that on some colleagues' machines, it has the same behavior as on mine, and on others, the message `Loading .NET Framework...` doesn't appear at all (or it is too fast to notice).

Do you have any idea how to get rid of that message short of reinstalling Excel?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer to my question from here:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/loading-net-framework-soooooo/m-p/2264145/highlight/true#M95862

> You can get rid of loading .net framework in Excel 2019 by doing File, Info, Check for Issues/Inspect Document and ticking Custom XML Data (you can tick everything else as well, but it will take a long time). It will tell you that Custom XML Data was found, so press Remove. Then close and save.
> Next time you open up, no .net framework, and it's much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same message **Loading .NET Framework...** when I accidentally opened Power Query in another window.

By closing Power Query everything disappeared.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34578024)